# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range Error - Morse to English Java Code

Tags: java

I am working on a Morse Code to English java code (below) in which | in Morse stands for a blank space between letters and numbers, and a blank space in Morse stands in between 2 letters or digits. For ex., "to be" = "- --- | -... ." in Morse.

```
// Import Scanner.
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project1_szhu1249322
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Would you like to translate 'Morse Code' to English, or 'English' to Morse code? (Enter 'Morse Code' or 'English'.)");
    String unit1 = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter a string of " + unit1 + " characters (for English, numbers and letters, only): ");
    String amountUnit1 = input.nextLine();
    if (unit1.equals("Morse Code"))
        toEnglish(amountUnit1);
    else if (unit1.equals("English"))
        toMorseCode(amountUnit1);
    else
        System.out.println("Invalid data. Enter 'Morse Code' or 'English' without the single quotes.");
}

    public static void toMorseCode(String english)
{
    // Declare variables, arrays, and strings.
    int i = 0;
    int l = english.length();
    int i2 = 2 * i;
    String[] lowerAlphabet = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"};
    String[] upperAlphabet = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"};
    String[] morseCode = {".-", "-...", "-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--.","....","..",".---","-.-",".-..","--","-.","---",".--.","--.-",".-.","...","-","..-","...-",".--","-..-","-.--","--..",".----","..---","...--","....-",".....","-....","--...","---..","----.","-----"};
    morseCode[i] = lowerAlphabet[i];
    StringBuilder morseBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    // for loops and if statements for result.
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
        i2 = 2 * i;
        if (english.charAt(i) != ' ')
            morseBuilder.append(morseCode[i2]);
        else
            morseBuilder.append('|');

        if (morseBuilder.charAt(i - 1) != ' ' && morseBuilder.charAt(i + 1) != 0)
            morseBuilder.append(' ');
    }

    morseCode[i] = upperAlphabet[i];
    // for loops and if statements for result.
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
        i2 = 2 * i;
        if (english.charAt(i) != ' ')
            morseBuilder.append(morseCode[i2]);
        else
            morseBuilder.append('|');

        if (morseBuilder.charAt(i - 1) != ' ' && morseBuilder.charAt(i + 1) != 0)
            morseBuilder.append(' ');
    }

    // Display results.
    System.out.println("The corresponding Morse code is " + morseBuilder + ".");
}

public static void toEnglish(String morse)
{
    // Declare variables, arrays, and strings.
    int i = 0;
    int l = morse.length();
    int i2 = i / 2;
    String[] lowerAlphabet = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"};
    String[] upperAlphabet = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"};
    String[] morseCode = {".-", "-...","-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--.","....","..",".---","-.-",".-..","--","-.","---",".--.","--.-",".-.","...","-","..-","...-",".--","-..-","-.--","--..",".----","..---","...--","....-",".....","-....","--...","---..","----.","-----"};
    morseCode[i] = upperAlphabet[i];
    String english;

    StringBuilder englishBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    // for loops and if statements for result.
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
        i2 = i / 2;
        if (morse.charAt(i) == '|')
        {
            englishBuilder.append(' ');
        }
        else
            englishBuilder.append(morseCode[i2]);
    }

    morseCode[i] = lowerAlphabet[i];
    // for loops and if statements for result.
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
        i2 = i / 2;
        if (morse.charAt(i) == '|')
        {
            englishBuilder.append(' ');
        }
        else
            englishBuilder.append(morseCode[i2]);
    }

    // Display results.
    System.out.println("The corresponding English is " + englishBuilder + ".");
    }
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
Would you like to translate 'Morse Code' to English, or 'English' to Morse code? (Enter 'Morse Code' or 'English'.)
English
Enter a string of English characters (for English, numbers and letters, only): 
to be
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.charAt(AbstractStringBuilder.java:237)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.charAt(StringBuilder.java:76)
    at Project1_szhu1249322.toMorseCode(Project1_szhu1249322.java:42)
    at Project1_szhu1249322.main(Project1_szhu1249322.java:16)
```

I do not understand why it is giving me this error message.

Also (*question 2*), what i2 value should I use? i / 2 only works for even i (when the first character is not a blank space. Help???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You failing on `morseBuilder.charAt(i - 1)` when `i==0`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is have multiple risky point. You will get exception when `i=0` at this code `charAt(i - 1)`.
Also in function `toEnglish` after the loop done, you will have value of `i` will equal to `l` so that next line `morseCode[i] = lowerAlphabet[i];` will cause the exception if your `morse` string is have length `>` the length of `morseCode` or `lowerAlphabet`

Answer (score 0):

Use maps to map your letters "A", "B" and so on to their morse counter parts and vice versa for morse to english. This allows you to know what to use when converting between the two. Try the following and modify it to fit your needs.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    String userInput = "Hello World";
    String converted = ConvertEnglishToMorseCode(userInput);

    System.out.println(userInput + " in Morse Code is " + converted);

    System.out.println(converted + " in English is " + ConvertMorseCodeToEnglish(converted));
} //end main

public static String ConvertMorseCodeToEnglish(String input)
{
    String[] upperAlphabet = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"};
    String[] morseCode = {".-", "-...", "-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--.","....","..",".---","-.-",".-..","--","-.","---",".--.","--.-",".-.","...","-","..-","...-",".--","-..-","-.--","--..",".----","..---","...--","....-",".....","-....","--...","---..","----.","-----"};
    HashMap<String, String> morseToEnlgish = new HashMap<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < upperAlphabet.length; i++)
        morseToEnlgish.put(morseCode[i], upperAlphabet[i]);

    String morseToEnglish = "";
    String[] morseSplit = input.split(" ");

    for(int i = 0; i < morseSplit.length; i++)
    {
        morseToEnglish += morseToEnlgish.containsKey(morseSplit[i]) ? morseToEnlgish.get(morseSplit[i]) : " ";
    }

    return morseToEnglish;
}

public static String ConvertEnglishToMorseCode(String input)
{
    String[] upperAlphabet = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"};
    String[] morseCode = {".-", "-...", "-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--.","....","..",".---","-.-",".-..","--","-.","---",".--.","--.-",".-.","...","-","..-","...-",".--","-..-","-.--","--..",".----","..---","...--","....-",".....","-....","--...","---..","----.","-----"};
    HashMap<String, String> englishToMorse = new HashMap<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < upperAlphabet.length; i++)
        englishToMorse.put(upperAlphabet[i], morseCode[i]);

    String[] letters = input.toUpperCase().split("");

    String englishToMorseWord = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++)
    {
        englishToMorseWord += englishToMorse.containsKey(letters[i]) ? englishToMorse.get(letters[i]) : "|";
        if(i < letters.length - 1)
            englishToMorseWord += " ";
    }

    return englishToMorseWord;
}
```

Output

```
Hello World in Morse Code is .... . .-.. .-.. --- | .-- --- .-. .-.. -..
.... . .-.. .-.. --- | .-- --- .-. .-.. -.. in English is HELLO WORLD
```

Note the slight differences in converting between the two. For English we split around "" to get every character by itself and use the mapping. For converting Morse to English we split around " " since I am assuming the letters in Morse code being given to you are in the format you are outputting when converting English words to Morse code, space separated. Lastly whenever we go from English to Morse Code and we don't have a mapping we fill in "|" and a " " when going from Morse Code to English.

Good Luck!